# Removing the green background for android icon

Tags: android, image, background

I'm new to android development and just created my first app. I selected my app icon, but don't know why the background of the image I saved, it's showing green whereas the original image doesn't have that. Is there any way that I can remove the green background. [image: The image after selecting in android studio.]

The above is the image after selecting it in android studio.

How can I remove the green background?

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

code structure

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/> // this is background color 
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

color resource found in `values/ic_launcher_background.xml` in your project dir

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ic_launcher_background">#00FF00</color> // change color using(#) like : #000000(black)
</resources>
```

I mentioned **black** color code,
you try to change color **according** to your **icon**.

or use transparent color like this

```
<color name="ic_launcher_background">#0000ffff</color> // transparent background color
```

Answer (score 1):

If you replaced the `ic_launcher_foreground.xml` to change the icon, you also need to remove the third line in the `ic_launcher.xml` and/or the `ic_launcher_round.xml` below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

In any case, what you see is the `ic_launcher_background.xml` in `/res/drawable/`. Delete it, see what breaks and repair it by removing the call to the deleted xml.

Comment: Actually I want the round icon also. I tried to remove the round icon but still the icon still shows green color.